# trying to add multiple computer accounts to an AD group using powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm trying badly to add multiple existing computer accounts to an AD group and i've tried the following syntax's but none worked:

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
foreach ($c in Get-Content c:\pacs_ws.txt) {
  add-QADGroupMember -identity 'S-1-5-21-436374069-152049171-725345543-20610' -Member $c
}
```

The SID is of the Group i want to add the computer account to

Another try: (Which worked with adding a list of users, but not working with a list of computer accounts) – Since both username and computername are AD objects which can be part of ADgroups I thought it should work the same…

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$computers = Get-Content c:\pacs_ws.txt #input list
foreach ($c in $computers) {
  add-QADGroupMember -identity 'CN=PacsWorkstationsGrp,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il' -Member $c
}
```

Another try:

```
foreach ($ws in Get-Content c:\pacs_ws.txt) {
  Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $ws -MemberOf 'CN=PacsWorkstationsGrp,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il'
```

### }

I've tried the updated script but it didn't work: 
Add-QADGroupMember : Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity: 'asuta.co.il\TAPC03521'.
At C:\Users\itaig\AppData\Local\Temp\61810980-c842-4014-a55a-a06a315520a6.ps1:5 char:21
+   Add-QADGroupMember <<<<  -Identity "S-1-5-21-436374069-152049171-725345543-20610" -Member "$dcPrefix$c"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-QADGroupMember], ObjectNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.DirectoryAccess.ObjectNotFoundException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Commands.AddGroupMemberCmdlet2

Now just to make sure the object exists in the directory:
DistinguishedName : CN=TAPC03521,OU=HQ,OU=Users Workstations,OU=Workstations,OU=Computers,OU=Accounts,DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il
DNSHostName       : TAPC03521.asuta.co.il
Enabled           : True
Name              : TAPC03521
ObjectClass       : computer
ObjectGUID        : 39ce0e58-aee7-4a1e-bc29-2178266f8ca4
SamAccountName    : TAPC03521$
SID               : S-1-5-21-436374069-152049171-725345543-8551

Comment: Can you show what your text file looks like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My text file looks like this and contains about 400 computer names:
TAPC03085
TAPC04498
TAPC04801
TAPC01157
TAPC02957

Itai

Comment: each computer account in a different line

Comment: Are you getting any error message at all?

Comment: Yes this is the error i get:
Add-QADGroupMember : Ambiguous identity: TAPC03090.
At line:1 char:62
+ foreach ($c in Get-Content c:\pacs_ws.txt){add-QADGroupMember <<<<  -identity 'CN=PacsWorkstationsGrp,OU=Security Groups,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,DC=asuta,DC=co,DC=il' -Member $c}
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-QADGroupMember], IdentityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.BusinessLogic.IdentityException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Commands.AddGroupMemberCmdlet2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-Content c:\pacs_ws.txt | foreach-object  { get-qadcomputer $_ | add-qadgroupmember -Identity PacsWorkstationsGrp }
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.
Itai

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using the Quest AD cmdlets, have you tried using `Get-QADComputer` to get the computer account and then pass that on as the `Member` property?

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory
$dcPrefix = "asuta.co.il\"
$computernames = Get-Content c:\pacs_ws.txt #input list
foreach ($c in $computernames) {
  Add-QADGroupMember -Identity "S-1-5-21-436374069-152049171-725345543-20610" -Member "$dcPrefix$c"
}
```

Alternatively, just prepend the Computer account name with the domain FQDN, instead of just the computer account name

Comment: Hey, from reading the script you wrote i was sure it's going to work but it didn't, the error i get is:
Add-QADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Member'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\itaig\AppData\Local\Temp\7d091a6f-0e7f-49a8-9c72-ef7b6d516f34.ps1:7 char:59
+   Add-QADGroupMember -Identity "$dcPrefix$groupCN" -Member <<<<  $computerAccount
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-QADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException

Comment: + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Commands.AddGroupMemberCmdlet2

Comment: What if you remove the `$computeraccount` variable, and just use `"$dcPrefix$c"` as the `member` property?

Comment: I've tried it already... it gives me the following error: Add-QADGroupMember : Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity: 'asuta.co.il\PacsWorkstationsGrp'.
It seems like the identity value is incorrect or something

Comment: Try with an alternative identity reference. Just updated the answer

Comment: Please update your answer, instead of flooding the comments